# C++ Passing vector to a function that is already passed

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

void func(vector<int> &vect) 
{ 
   vect.push_back(30); 
   extra_func(vect);
} 

void extra_func(vector<int> &vect) 
{ 
   vect.push_back(40); 
} 

int main(){ 
    vector<int> vect; 
    vect.push_back(10); 
    vect.push_back(20); 

    func(vect); 

    for (int i=0; i<vect.size(); i++) 
       cout << vect[i] << " "; 

    return 0; 
}
```

I want to pass a vector again to other function that has been passed. But this seems to not work. How could I implement something like this

Comment: You mean, that you don't get 40 in your output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code doesn't compile because `func()` doesn't know about `extra_func()`. You either need a function declaration (sometimes called a function prototype) or to rearrange your functions.

```
void extra_func(vector<int> &); // declaration

void func(vector<int> &vect) 
{ 
   vect.push_back(30); 
   extra_func(vect);
} 

void extra_func(vector<int> &vect) // definition
{ 
   vect.push_back(40); 
}
```

or

```
void extra_func(vector<int> &vect) // now it's visible to func()
{ 
   vect.push_back(40); 
} 

void func(vector<int> &vect) 
{ 
   vect.push_back(30); 
   extra_func(vect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises as you are calling `extra_func` without `func` knowing about it so you must initialize `extra_func` before `func`
Your code should be like

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

void extra_func(vector<int> &vect) 
{ 
   vect.push_back(40); 
} 

void func(vector<int> &vect) 
{ 
   vect.push_back(30); 
   extra_func(vect);
} 

int main(){ 
    vector<int> vect; 
    vect.push_back(10); 
    vect.push_back(20); 

    func(vect); 

    for (int i=0; i<vect.size(); i++) 
       cout << vect[i] << " "; 

    return 0; 
}
```